# How to join columns from the same table?

Tags: sql-server

How to add extra column with time difference for the same SALESID and GO = SO and GO = ZW?

```
select SALESID, DATETIME AS Time, GO
FROM [Mer_PRD].[dbo].[TRACKINGTABLE]
WHERE GO IN('ZW', 'SO')
```

[image]

Result example:

```
****SALESID**     |      TIME SO        |      TIME ZW        |  DIFF**  

ZS/0033428/2020   | 2020-07-16 08:37:00 | 2020-07-16 08:40:00 | 00:03:00
```

Comment: Please share your DDL and Sample data or provide a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18)

Comment: Formatted text is better/preferred over images (that one is impossible to see), DDL/DML is the best.

Comment: @DaleK http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1f152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a self join.

```
SELECT goSO.SALESID
, goSo.[Time] 'TIME SO'
, goZw.[Time] 'TIME ZW'
,   cast(goZw.[Time] - goSo.[Time] as Time) Difference
FROM GOTRACKING  goSo
INNER JOIN GOTRACKING goZw on goSo.SALESID = goZw.SALESID
WHERE goSo.[GO] = 'SO' 
AND goZw.[GO] = 'ZW'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1f152/10/0)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT SALESID, Time FROM [Mer_PRD].[dbo].[TRACKINGTABLE]

;WITH cte AS (SELECT SALESID, Time, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY SALESID ORDER BY Time) AS RN
              FROM [Mer_PRD].[dbo].[TRACKINGTABLE])
SELECT a.SALESID, a.Time, b.Time AS Time2
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
 ON a.SALESID = b.SALESID
  AND a.RN = b.RN -1
WHERE a.RN = 1
```